# Find a regular expression not preceded by and not followed by

Tags: java, regex, string, expression

I'm trying to find the right regular expression, but nothing works exactly as I expect.

In Java I'm using the String's function split(String regex).
I have a list of strings (which are in fact names of music albums).
What I want is to split the strings by the the character '-' and use only the first two strings of the resulting array.

For example, I have the following strings:

```
Beyonce-BDay-2006-RNS
Big_Sean-Finally_Famous-2011-CR
Black_Eyed_Peas-The_E.N.D-2009-H3X
Bob_Sinclar-Soundz_Of_Freedom-CD-2007-OBC
Britney_Spears-Femme_Fatale-2011-H3X
Chris_Brown-F.A.M.E.-2011-H3X
David_Guetta_-_One_Love-2009-MOD
Jay-Z-Blueprint_2.1-2003-RNS
Jennifer_Lopez-Love-2011-CaHeSo
Kanye_West-808s_And_Heartbreaks-2008-H3X
Katy_Perry-Teenage_Dream-2010-CR
Ne-Yo-Year_Of_The_Gentleman-2008-FLM
Pitbull-Rebelution-2009-NOiR
```

I use the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    str = strings[i];
    String[] parts = str.split("-");
    System.out.println(parts[0].replace('_', ' ').trim() + " - " + parts[1].replace('_', ' ').trim());
}
```

And as a result I get:

```
Beyonce - BDay
Big Sean - Finally Famous
Black Eyed Peas - The E.N.D
Bob Sinclar - Soundz Of Freedom
Britney Spears - Femme Fatale
Chris Brown - F.A.M.E.
David Guetta - One Love
Jay - Z
Jennifer Lopez - Love
Kanye West - 808s And Heartbreaks
Katy Perry - Teenage Dream
Ne - Yo
Pitbull - Rebelution
```

Everything is fine except of two strings:

```
Jay-Z-Blueprint_2.1-2003-RNS
Ne-Yo-Year_Of_The_Gentleman-2008-FLM
```

The problem there is that the first hyphen ('-') is, of-course, a part of the artist's name.

So, my regex have to be something else that will exclude those exceptions.
I tried this regex:

```
(?<!Jay)(?<!Ne)(?!Z)(?!Yo)-
```

Which works fine, but if I add the following strings to the list:

```
Jay-Good-1996-RNS
Ne-Alright-2000-RNS
```

I get:

```
Jay-Good - 1996
Ne-Alright - 2000
```

Instead of:

```
Jay - Good
Ne - Alright
```

I tried a lot of other expressions but nothing works.
I would very appreciate if someone could help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have to use that file format or could you use something like CSV format instead?

Comment: If you can, use a different format; this will get very difficult to parse. If you can't use a different format, please tell us where exactly hyphens can appear as part of the value and how many. It might be impossible...

Comment: Since I assume that both the artist names and album names can contain hyphens, this is impossible to parse correctly.

Comment: There is no consistency in any part of your strings.  I doubt you can sort them out.

Comment: I know that both can contain hyphens but I have specific words which I know that are integral like Jay-Z. I would like to add them somehow to the regex so that they will be ignored.
The regex should not be generic but specific with few "saved" words to take into account.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot do it!

Even though you can use regex to split the string:

```
Ne-Yo-Year_Of_The_Gentleman-2008-FLM
```

up until the year, and get the following:

```
Ne-Yo-Year_Of_The_Gentleman
```

Now how will you decide which is the first name and which is the last ?

**Options:**
First name: Ne
Last name: Yo-Year_Of_The_Gentleman

First name: Ne-Yo
Last name: Year_Of_The_Gentleman

and there's no way to determine which is the "correct" output!

Comment: There is no reliable way to cut off `2008-FLM` either.

Comment: @PM77-1 if the string always ends with `dash, four digit number (year), dash and more than one letter` - then you can generate a regex with a non-capturing group that includes the above.

Comment: But it is **not** the case. See `ob_Sinclar-Soundz_Of_Freedom-CD-2007-OBC`

Comment: @PM77-1 indeed you are right! I didn't notice this case.

Comment: My point is that there are only few "saved" words like Jay-Z, Ne-Yo etc. and I want to add them to the regex as constant exception.
The regex should not be generic but specific with those expected words...

Comment: @LionGod8 if you know the list of exceptions in advance, save them in a data-structure and check every item if it's there - don't try to make your regex more complex because it'll cost you with running time and maintainability issues.

Answer (score 0):

To create exceptions to your split delimiter you can use lookarounds like this:

```
(?<!Jay|Ne)-(?!Z|Yo)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oJ6bG2/1)

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/oJ6bG2/4

Look at the last two lines. This is not answering my requests.
Only the combination Jay-Z and Ne-Yo should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
  import re
  print re.sub(r"-\d{4}.*","",x)
```

Tried this in python.It's working fine.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this regex for substitution: `(-CD)?-[0-9]{4}-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$` - http://regex101.com/r/vN2uH2/1

Considering all strings are ended with "-YEAR-NAME", which YEAR takes 4 numbers and NAME takes any one or more characters including numbers and may be prepended by "-CD".

Here is something else that you could try: `^[^-]+(-[a-zA-Z]{1,3})?-[^-]+` - http://regex101.com/r/eL6jW2/1

Comment: What about `CD-2007-OBC` and `2011-CaHeSo`?

Comment: Are you sure that OP showed all his data?  Are you going to modify your regex with each new sample?

Comment: @PM77-1 included "-CD" optional, but there is nothing wrong with `2011-CaHeSo`. Without more info there's no way to magically get a perfect regex, don't you agree?

Comment: I say that it's **impossible** to solve this problem with just regex. Format is too liquid.

Answer (score -2):

This should be the replacement pattern you run first.  So we strip away to the end of the line matching dash year(4 digits) dash word characters (numbers and letters).  After that you can replace '_' with space and not worry about dashes.

```
replace("-(\\d){4}-(\\w)+$", '')
```

Comment: `ob_Sinclar-Soundz_Of_Freedom-CD-2007-OBC`